# flutter onGenerateRoute with BuildContext

Tags: flutter

I would like to generate my iOS (Cupertino routes) using an onGenerateRoute function:

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  ...
  return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => SomePage(context), title: "SomeTitle");
  ...
}
```

Now the title (specified as 'SomeTitle') is language dependend, so I need to get it like this:

```
MyLocalizations.of(context).somePageTitle
```

But for this, I need the `BuildContext` (context).

How do I do this? I could specify the `BuildContext` as a parameter to every route, but that does not work for the initial route (am I wrong?).

What is the best way to get the `BuildContext` in onGenerateRoute?

Comment: When using `pushNamed` you can pass the localized text and retrieve it in `onGenerateRoute` using `settings.name`.

Comment: But then I have the same problem: How do I do this with the initial route?

Comment: Do you mean with simple `routes:`?

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK:** There is no other way to get `BuildContext` in onGenerateRoute. The only way is we got as an argument (The way we got in `builder`).

---

**ALTERNATE WAY**

If you go through the documentation of `CupertinoPageRoute` `title` property

> A title string for this route.
>
> Used to auto-populate [CupertinoNavigationBar] and
>   [CupertinoSliverNavigationBar]'s `middle`/`largeTitle` widgets when
>   one is not manually supplied.

So title you have provided at `CupertinoPageRoute` will be used as a fallback, only if you have not provided middle widget into `CupertinoNavigationBar` or `CupertinoSliverNavigationBar`

So in your case, alternatively you can explicitly set middle widget and title you want there.

Example:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text(MyLocalizations.of(context).somePageTitle),
      ),
      body: Container(),//Body as you want
    );
  }
```